# Automatic request to http://localhost:3000/null route with Node(mon) and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently working on a project with Node, Express, and Mongoose. I have an issue where for some reason my localhost:3000 server is sending an automatic request to the `/null` path. This leads to my program crashing for several pages because it cannot find this path. I have created a very basic express app to highlight the issue:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(morgan('tiny'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Home page');
});

app.get('/dogs', (req, res) => {
    res.send('WOOF WOOF');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

If I now go to the home page, 2 outputs are printed to the console:

```
GET / 304 - - 0.934 ms
GET /null 404 143 - 0.310 ms
```

The same is true for the `/test` path, and any other path I create for that matter.

When I check the network requests in Chrome, I can also see that there is a request for `/null` being initiated from the `index.js` file (which you see above). There is nothing else to this express app and I have only installed the express and morgan packages.

The question is why an automatic request to the `/null` path is sent. That is definitely not normal behavior. Anybody that can help me answer this question?

Thanks in advance!

### My package.json

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you start your server? Can you show us your package.json? Especially the commands part.

Comment: I don't seem to see a problem with your index.js file, I even tried to replicate the issue in case there is something I am missing, but it works fine. As @Geshode said, the issue could be with your package.json scripts section.

Comment: I've added the package.json file. I've tried to run the exact same program in a different directory and had the same issue. I am starting my server with Nodemon.

Comment: Thank god, found the issue. It was a Chrome extension messing with the server requests.